# What's the logic behind "cumsum" to make flags, compute counts and form groups?

Tags: python, pandas

Without further ado, my input (s1) & expected-output (df) are below :

```
#INPUT
s1 = pd.Series(['a', np.nan, 'b', 'c', np.nan, np.nan, 'd', np.nan]).rename('col1')

#EXPECTED-OUTPUT
s2 = pd.Series([1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6]).rename('col2') # flag the transition null>notnull or vice-versa
s3 = pd.Series([0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 3, 0, 4]).rename('col3') # counter of the null values
df = pd.concat([s1, s2, s3], axis=1)

  col1  col2  col3
0    a     1     0
1  NaN     2     1
2    b     3     0
3    c     3     0
4  NaN     4     2
5  NaN     4     3
6    d     5     0
7  NaN     6     4
```

I tried plenty of weird combinations of cumsum and masks but without any success. Likely that's because I don't have the basics of the logical thinking. What questions do I need to ask myself before starting to build the chain that will give me my series ?

Any help would be greately appreciated, guys !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`isna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.isna.html) with [`cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) and [`where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html) for "col3". For "col2" a classical [`ne`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.ne.html)+[`shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html)/[`cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html):

```
m = df['col1'].isna()

# if the flag is different from the previous one, increment
df['col2'] = m.ne(m.shift()).cumsum()

# increment on each True, mask the False
df['col3'] = m.cumsum().where(m, 0)
```

Output:

```
  col1  col2  col3
0    a     1     0
1  NaN     2     1
2    b     3     0
3    c     3     0
4  NaN     4     2
5  NaN     4     3
6    d     5     0
7  NaN     6     4
```

Intermediates:

```
  col1  col2  col3      m m.shift()  m.ne(m.shift())  m.cumsum()
0    a     1     0  False       NaN             True           0
1  NaN     2     1   True     False             True           1
2    b     3     0  False      True             True           1
3    c     3     0  False     False            False           1
4  NaN     4     2   True     False             True           2
5  NaN     4     3   True      True            False           3
6    d     5     0  False      True             True           3
7  NaN     6     4   True     False             True           4
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I can't believe it was this easy! I wonder if you read my last question in the post. Did you had the exact combinations of methods in mind before approaching col2 and col3 ? Is there a pattern I need to know ? I would be so grateful if you can suggest something to improve my logical thinking.

Comment: @VERBOSE the col2 is a classical one, for col3 it was just obvious to me: count and mask the unwanted.